# Diferencas entre Python e JavaScript em relação a arrays?

Tags: javascript, python, array, característica-linguagem

Estou com uma certa dificuldade porque no JavaScript era possível fazer isso:

```
const x = []
x[0] = 1
x[1] = 2
```

Mas no Python quando eu crio uma lista vazia e tento fazer uma declaração ele diz que o índice está fora do range. Consigo contornar com o método `append()` mas queria saber se tem uma forma de poder fazer como no JavaScript.

Comment: Não vejo como fazer isso se não inicializar a lista do tamanho necessário, mas principalmente não vejo motivos de se fazer isso. Dependendo da sua necessidade, talvez seja mais interessante utilizar um dicionário. Qual é o objetivo?

Comment: Como definir o tamanho?

Comment: Pode descrever o que pretende fazer? Existe a real necessidade de informar a chave ao armazenar um valor?

Comment: Na verdade pensando bem acho que não preciso saber a chave, só quero criar uma lista de times que é uma lista de jogadores que são objetos.

Comment: Posso usar um for normal pra printar todos os objetos de uma lista ou há um método mais apropriado?

Comment: Para adicionar é pelo `append` mesmo. Sim, percorre a lista por um `for`.

Comment: E se eu tiver uma lista dentro de uma lista devo usar dois for ou há outra forma?

Comment: chaves de dicionarios podem conter espacos?

Comment: Sobre chaves de dicionário: melhor você fazer outra pergunta. Mas em resumo - se forem uma string, podem conter espaços e qualquer caractere. Mas no seu caso pode ser mais interessante usar "tuplas": números separados por vírgula - para as chaves do seu dicionário. Isso é uma forma simples de trabalhar com matrizes multidimensionais em Python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apesar de sintaxe idêntica, semanticamente o que é produzido com ela é muito diferente em cada linguagem.

Em Pyhton esse código realmente produz uma lista. Em JavaScript o que está criando é um dicionário, também conhecido como mapa ou *array* associativo.

Em Python há outra sintaxe para criar um dicionário.

Em JavaScript há uma otimização para tratar um dicionário como *array*, sempre que possível. Na verdade este é o termo usado, mas ele parece mais uma lista do que um *array*.

Um *array* ou uma lista se caracteriza por ter os elementos em sequência e densamente, podendo acessá-los com complexidade O(1), ou seja, qualquer acesso é feito em uma operação de forma direta.

Um dicionário é esparso e não tem ordem nos elementos. Apesar de acessar cada elemento em O(1), não é de forma direta, é preciso calcular onde está a chave, já que ela não tem ordem e pode nem existir.

Um dicionário geralmente cria uma chave nova automaticamente quando tenta colocar um valor em uma chave não existente. Quando se faz isto provavelmente inibirá otimizações para tratar o dicionário como uma lista, mas depende de implementação.

Como em Python não há esta confusão de conceitos na mesma sintaxe precisa ser explícito do que quer.

Se puder usar uma lista, use, mesmo que tenha que adaptar o código um pouco. Se for realmente necessário criar um dicionário, então vá por ele. Mas não crie o dicionário só para ficar parecido com JS ou só para escrever um código aparentemente mais simples. Uma lista sempre é mais vantagem que um dicionário se os elementos são usados em ordem com sequência completa de números.

Eventualmente até quando parece um dicionário pode ser mais vantajoso para performance e memória usar uma lista no lugar do dicionário mesmo quando faltam alguns elementos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Só para complementar: para criar uma lista com tamanho pré-definido  em Python, uma forma é criar uma lista contendo apenas um elemento imutável (em geral `None` ou `0`), e fazer uma multiplicação pelo tamanho desejado. A "multiplicação" por um inteiro N é definida para sequências em Python como "concatenar a sequência com ela mesma N vezes":
`x = [0,] * 5`  cria uma lista com 5 elementos pré-alocados. **é importante não usar isso pra criar listas dentro de listas** quando se quer criar uma matriz 2D - (as listas internas serão clones entre si). Se precisar, a indicação é usar o NumPy.