# Como optimizar meu acesso ao dicionário do Python?

Tags: python, dicionário

Tenho um dicionário da sequinte forma:

`dicionario = {'1':'Banana','7':'Maçã','3':'Pera','2':'Melancia'}`

Se eu verificar a chave `'2'` no dicionário: `if '2' in dicionario:`. Minha intuição de programador me diz que a complexidade desse comando é  `O(n)` no pior caso, pois existem n elementos dentro desse dicionário. Porém isso é um dicionário e não uma lista e não sei exatamente como as "engrenagens mágicas" do dicionário do python funcionam.

A complexidade de realizar uma busca em um determinado item do dicionário seja procurando a chave como eu fiz ou acessando o elemento direto: `dicionario['2']` possui complexidade `O(n)`? Ou existe um Hash dentro dessas "engrenagens" ou alguma estrutura que consegue optimizar essa busca, como a busca binária?

Em falar em busca binária, há alguma forma de acessar o elemento de um dicionário como eu fiz e ativar uma busca binárias nas "engrenagens" do dicionário considerando, é claro, que ele esteja ordenado?

Comment: O dicionário é implementado como hash table e no acesso direto a complexidade é O(1). Ver https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#how-are-dictionaries-implemented

Comment: ponha o link para a docuementação do Python 3. O google é último lugar do mundo que fica com esses links para a documentação do Python 2 ainda - só que ele só vai melhorar se os links que a gente põe pela internet forem para a versão 3.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#how-are-dictionaries-implemented

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Até onde eu sei as duas formas de acessar uma chave no dicionário são basicamente equivalentes (claro uma retorna um booleano da existência e o outro retorna o valor, mas ambas conseguem tempo O(1), na maioria dos casos (tem casos extremos que pode ser O(n), mas que não chegam nem perto de ocorrer)).

Dicionários são [tabelas de espalhamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27827/101), elas possuem performance quase ao do *array* para acesso aleatório, só perde um pouco porque precisa calcular o código *hash* antes de acessar o elemento. Existem casos de colisão de chaves onde a busca precisa ser feita de outra forma, podendo até mesmo chegar em [complexidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33319/101) O(n).

Um dicionário é quase o oposto de uma estrutura que permite busca binária. Um dicionário não pode estar nem [ordenado (com regra específica), muito menos classificado (com critério determinado)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168531/101).

No exemplo tenho dúvidas se um [*array*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199751/101) não seria a melhor escolha.

Tanto o *array*,quanto o dicionário terá complexidade O(n) para procurar por valores.

Já demonstrei que o [dicionário é diferente do *array*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/244255/101).

Pode ser útil: [Objetos são semelhantes a arrays?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122341/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

Como está nos comentários e na outra resposta, dicionários em Python são uma tabela de hash, com tempo de busca O(1) - e a informação sobre isso está aqui: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#how-are-dictionaries-implemented

Dito isso, sobre o design de código que você pergunta - `chave in dict` vs `dict[chave]`: o tempo de acesso é o mesmo - só que se a chave não existir, a segunda forma levanta uma exceção.

Quando você vai recupear um valor que não tem certeza se existe no dicionário o recomendado é usar o método `.get`:

```
meu_valor = dicionario.get("chave")
```

Nesse caso, se "chave" não existir, o `.get` retorna None e a vida continua. O `.get` também aceita um segundo parâmetro que é o retornado quando a chave não existe, em vez de None.

Isso economiza linhas de código - do tipo

```
if chave in dicionario:
    valor = dicionario[chave]
else: 
    valor = None
```

ou

```
try:
   valor = dicionario[chave]
except KeyError:
   valor = None
```

Desses, esse segundo caso seria o único que teria alguma diferença de performance, por conta do tempo de criação do contexto do try/except .
Veja também o método `.setdefault` dos `dict`s: eles não só recuperam um valor padrão caso não exista um - mas nesse caso, fazem a atribuição do novo valor. Por exemplo, um loop para criar um dicionário com todas as palavras de um texto e  a posição de cada palavra dentro do mesmo, numa lista, poderia ser:

```
palavras = texto.split()
posicoes = {}
for indice, palavra in enumerate(palavras):
    posicoes.setdefault(palavra, []).append(indice)
```

Nesse caso, se a palavra ainda não foi encontrada, é criada uma lista vazia que é ao mesmo tempo atribuida lá e retornada pelo método. Se `posicoes[palavra]` já existe, a lista existente é retornada.

Agora, já que você se interessa por isso e quer saber sobre busca binária, aqui vai o fato interessante: o Python tem uma interface bem definida para objetos do tipo "Mapping" - e é bme tranquilo implementar um objeto que se comporte exatamente como um dicionário, mas com os algoritmos internos que você decidir. Se você quiser criar um dicionário que internamente seja uma árvore binária, é bem fácil - a forma recomendada de se fazer isso é herdar a classe `collections.abc.MutableMapping`. Há várias classes em `collections.abc` que são a base para implementar estruturas de dados bem uteis e variadas. Uma árvore binaria teria busca O(log(n)), mas com a vantagem de você poder ter ordenação das chaves e poder usar slices na mesma, por exemplo. Confira em: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html

Eu tenho vários "superdicionários" implementados no módulo `extradict`  - alguns são mais de brinquedo, outros eu uso mesmo em produção:

https://github.com/jsbueno/extradict

Comment: Sobre o `extradict`: eu não uso nada Python em produção, mas ja aprendi muito com esse projeto